# VS Cordova: is there any way to apply different config.xml settings depending on chosen configuration?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

I need to use different app IDs, since was given two provisioning profiles for com.myapp and com.beta.myapp. For now I have to change widget:id in config.xml every time I change the current configuration from Debug to Release and vice versa. Can this be automated? I know I can tweak .jsproj by implementing a BeforeBuild/BuildDependsOn handler, even using web.config transformations. Is there a simpler, preferably built-in way to do the same thing?

Note: customizing node.js and/or VS files is not an option, as I prefer modifying files that are part of the project repository to be able to store and distribute the changes along with codebase.

Comment: I haven't tried it with Tools for Apache Cordova project, but have you considered using [SlowCheetah]( https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5?SRC=VSIDE) and using Transforms on the config.xml?

Comment: @mharr, I tried installing it to VS 2013 SP4 and it does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been resolved.

First off, create the following files in res\native\ios\cordova:

```c
// build.xcconfig
// The file contains general iOS settings, e.g.
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = <your iOS identity>
```

```c
// build-debug.xcconfig
// The file contains beta specific iOS settings
#include "build.xcconfig"
BUNDLE_ID = com.your.app.beta
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = <profile GUID>
```

```c
// build-release.xcconfig
// The file contains release specific iOS settings
#include "build.xcconfig"
BUNDLE_ID = com.your.app
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = <profile GUID>
```

See [Build Settings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) for complete list of supported settings. Note that the `BUNDLE_ID` is a custom constant that is explained below.

If you want to have the files grouped together in Solution Explorer, just edit your .jsproj file as follows:

```xml
<Content Include="res\native\ios\cordova\build.xcconfig" />
<Content Include="res\native\ios\cordova\build-debug.xcconfig">
  <DependentUpon>build.xcconfig</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="res\native\ios\cordova\build-release.xcconfig">
  <DependentUpon>build.xcconfig</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Finally, edit your config.xml as follows:

```xml
<widget ... id="com.your.app" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="$(BUNDLE_ID)">
    ...
</widget>
```

This will set the iOS bundle ID to whatever value you assigned in the target .xcconfig.

Answer (score 0):

A Cordova hook might be a way to accomplish this. [Here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/hooks-apache-cordova-mobile-applications/) is an article on how Cordova hooks work. You might want to have write up a before_prepare hook and update the config.xml before the native platform is prepared and compiled.

Comment: I recall I tried using the hooks some time ago but to no avail. This seems to work only when you manage a Cordova project directly, e.g. in XCode, but not when using VS and Cordova Tools. Please see https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6583658-add-support-for-cordova-hooks.